# line up buttons html

Tags: html, css

I have a page that displays some info about a project in a "container", within that container there are some different fields along with 2 buttons that access different pages.  I am having an issue getting the buttons to line up horizontally, how can I get this done?  I am thinking it has something to do with the way the forms are rendered, is there a better way than forms?  can you style forms with css doing like

> display: inline

This is the first time I have messed around with HTML, here is my code thanks:

```
<div class="project-container">
    <label class="boldLabel">Project ID:</label>
    <span><?php echo $pId; ?></span><br>
    <label class="boldLabel">Project Owner:</label>
    <span><?php echo $pName; ?></span><br>
    <label class="boldLabel">Project Description:</label>
    <span><?php echo $pDesc; ?> </span><br><br>
    <label class="boldLabel">Project Due Date:</label>
    <span><?php echo $dDate; ?> </span><br>
        <form action="delete.php" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" name="pId" value="<?php echo $pId; ?>">
            <button class="buttonDelete" type="submit" name="delete">Delete Project</button>
        </form>
        <form action="update.php" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" name="pId" value="<?php echo $pId; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="pName" value="<?php echo $pName; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="pDesc" value="<?php echo $pDesc; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="dDate" value="<?php echo $dDate; ?>">
            <button class="buttonUpdate" type="submit" name="update">Update Project</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any 2 forms on your file. You just need 1 general form tag that handles both process (delete and update). These process can be managed throught Javascript functions and events.

**Note:** The problem about the 2 buttons not being aligned horizontally is because you have certain elements on different form tags. You could do some extra work with css but having 2 forms in one file is normally avoided by developers unless this could be the only way to a certain process.

I fixed the code. You can see the snippet working here:

```js
function buttoncheck(action)
  {
  //$("project-container").load("process.php", {action: action});   
  // This is an example of how you could "call" process.php
  }
```

```html
<form action="process.php" method="post">

<div id="project-container" class="project-container">
    <label class="boldLabel">Project ID:</label>
    <span><?php echo $pId; ?></span><br>
    <label class="boldLabel">Project Owner:</label>
    <span><?php echo $pName; ?></span><br>
    <label class="boldLabel">Project Description:</label>
    <span><?php echo $pDesc; ?> </span><br><br>
    <label class="boldLabel">Project Due Date:</label>
    <span><?php echo $dDate; ?> </span><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="pId" value="<?php echo $pId; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="pId" value="<?php echo $pId; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="pName" value="<?php echo $pName; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="pDesc" value="<?php echo $pDesc; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="dDate" value="<?php echo $dDate; ?>">

        <button class="buttonDelete" type="button" name="delete" onClick="buttoncheck(0)">Delete Project</button>
        <button class="buttonUpdate" type="button" name="update" onClick="buttoncheck(1)">Update Project</button>
        
             
    </div>
    </form>
```

And in the "process.php" file

```
<?php

$action=$_POST['action'];

// To Update

if($action=1){

// update code here

}

if($action=0){

// delete code here

}
```

You can check how to refresh div content, onclick function, css manage in this links:

[Load jquery method](http://mrbool.com/how-to-refresh-div-content-using-jquery/33213)

[Load Jquery method 2](http://phppot.com/jquery/jquery-div-auto-load-and-refresh/)

[onclick function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)

[button css design process](https://designshack.net/articles/css/css-button-tutorial-how-to-code-buttons-in-5-simple-steps/)

Comment: Thanks @Julio Perez the look is what I am going for.  So when it goes to process.php I could do if(isset('delete')){. . . }?

Comment: great answer thanks @Julio Perez, I would up-vote, but being new to SO it doesn't let me

Comment: One more quick question, what does function buttoncheck() do?

Comment: if you click on delete button the function buttoncheck() will pass the 0 value to process.php throught "action" parameter if you click uptade button it will pass 1 value to process.php throught "action" parameter. That way you will know on process.php file when an update or a delete happens.